# How to test (programmatically) whether the current Emacs session (among several) is running the Emacs server?

Tags: server

The `server-running-p` predicate will evaluate to `t` if the Emacs server is running, irrespective of which Emacs session currently "owns" the server process.

Therefore, when there are two or more independent Emacs sessions running simultaneously, `server-running-p` does not really test whether the ***current*** Emacs session is running the server.

I'm looking for a more specific test, one that will evaluate to `t` *if and only if* the current session (i.e. the session performing the test) is running the Emacs server.

Comment: Cannot test right now but maybe you can test if server-mode is non-nil.

Comment: @YoungFrog: thanks for the suggestion, but in every situation I tested (namely, after `server-start` and after `server-force-delete`), `server-mode` was always `nil`.

Comment: I think YoungFrog's suggestion is a good one, but you need to call `(server-mode 1)` rather than calling `(server-start)`. The former invokes the latter, and `server-force-delete` also checks and disables this mode, so it rather looks like `sever-mode` is the intended interface, and we shouldn't be calling `server-start` directly.

Comment: That said, using `server-mode` still doesn't account for the same server being started and deleted via multiple Emacs instances, as deleting the server from one instance has no effect on the value of `server-mode` in another.

Answer (score 6):

You might check:

```el
(and (boundp 'server-process)
     (processp server-process)
     (server-running-p))
```

That should work provided that you've avoided starting a server in the other instances.

Assuming a socket-based server, if you were to start a second Emacs instance, and forcibly delete and then restart the server process from that second instance, then the above code will still return non-nil in the original instance (as the same socket directory will be in use), leaving you in the original situation.

(Obviously this isn't ideal, so there may well be a better solution.)

`server-running-p` tells you whether a particular named server (defaulting to `server-name`) is running; so if your `server-name` is the same in all of your instances, then you can avoid starting an already-running server like so:

```
;; Start server (but don't restart).
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```